# malformed header from script. Bad header=<!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: perl, header, perl-module, www-mechanize

I am receiving the following server error on a perl script:

> malformed header from script. Bad
> header=:
> youtube_perl.pl,

Here is my source code:

```
#!"C:\XAMPP\perl\bin\perl.exe" -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $q = CGI->new;

my $url = 'http://www.youtube.com';

my $mechanize = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);

$mechanize->get($url);

my $page = $mechanize->content();

print $page;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Figured it out.  Had to add the following before I attempted to print the page:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

I guess perl can not print html pages without defining the header first.

Comment: @user589294 - No. Perl can print them. But they won't be valid HTTP responses. So if you want your HTML page printed by Perl to be transported over HTTP you need to actually print a full HTTP response - got nothing to do with Perl

Comment: Of course Perl can print HTML pages without a header!  You can't write a CGI script without printing a header, though.
Better is: `print $q->header();`.  See [perldoc CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html).

Comment: You should use `\x0D\x0A` rather than `\n` as the EOL when speaking HTTP. HTTP specifies that lines should be terminated with CR-LF whereas `\n` is the end of line marker for your current environment, `\n` just happens to be `\x0D\x0A` for you because you're running on Windows.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! What is strange is our old scripts were working without this, and one day stopped work. Could have been a server update. Not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: in bash/shell \n signs are in echo not interpreted but echo adds \n automatically, so it is needed one more echo command for the output

Answer (score 3):

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

Use `\n\n` without this it will not print anything it will give:

> Malformed header from script error

In your error log file.